# PHP - Group together different parts of array to add to database

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array from a CSV import that I want to group together based on an ID.

The structure is as follows:

Each row is a measure and a comment added to a submission. There can be multiple rows for one submission. For example, if there are 3 measures, then the headline submission data will be repeated 3 times, with different comments/measure details.

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => Lot
                [2] => Lot Submission
                [3] => Lot Submission
                [4] => Lot Submission
                [5] => LNW North
                [6] => C Spencer Ltd
                [7] => Panel
                [8] => 1
                [9] => Buildings
                [10] => 2015/2016
                [11] => 2
                [12] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
                [13] => Testing notes
                [14] => KPI1 - Behavioural Safety
                [15] => PER1 - Health, Safety, and Wellbeing strategy
                [16] => Testing Comment 1
                [17] => Expected
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => Lot
                [2] => Lot Submission
                [3] => Lot Submission
                [4] => Lot Submission
                [5] => LNW North
                [6] => C Spencer Ltd
                [7] => Panel
                [8] => 1
                [9] => Buildings
                [10] => 2015/2016
                [11] => 2
                [12] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
                [13] => Testing notes
                [14] => KPI1 - Behavioural Safety
                [15] => PMTEST - Test
                [16] => Testing 2
                [17] => Stretch
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => Lot
                [2] => Lot Submission
                [3] => Lot Submission
                [4] => Lot Submission
                [5] => LNW North
                [6] => C Spencer Ltd
                [7] => Panel
                [8] => 1
                [9] => Buildings
                [10] => 2015/2016
                [11] => 2
                [12] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
                [13] => Testing notes
                [14] => KPI1 - Behavioural Safety
                [15] => JP001 - Jamie
                [16] => Testing 3
                [17] => Excellence
            )
```

`Parts 0-13 of each array are the same, this is the headline information for each submission.` I want to try and add the 14th - 17th parts of the array to a new array. An example is below

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => Lot
        [2] => Lot Submission
        [3] => Lot Submission
        [4] => Lot Submission
        [5] => LNW North
        [6] => C Spencer Ltd
        [7] => Panel
        [8] => 1
        [9] => Buildings
        [10] => 2015/2016
        [11] => 2
        [12] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
        [13] => Testing notes
        ['measure'] = array(
            [0] = array(
                [14] => KPI1 - Behavioural Safety
                [15] => PER1 - Health, Safety, and Wellbeing strategy
                ['comments'] = array(
                    [16] => Testing Comment 1
                    [17] => Expected
                )
            ),
            [1] = array(
                [14] => KPI1 - Behavioural Safety
                [15] => PMTEST - Test
                ['comments'] = array(
                    [16] => Testing 2
                    [17] => Stretch
                )
            ),
            [2] = array(
                [14] => KPI1 - Behavioural Safety
                [15] => JP001 - Jamie
                ['comments'] = array(
                    [16] => Testing 3
                    [17] => Excellence
                )
            )
        )                   
    )
```

I am totally stumped, but have no idea where to start. Can I create a new array and push the data to it depending on the submission ID (`[0] => 1` of the array)?

Any help or guidance will be such a massive help

Answer (score 1):

This code will convert the array into a new array of the format you said you wanted.

The only difference being it does not keep the original occurances counts in the `measure` and `comments` arrays. I could not see why they needed to be that same, but if you think they should be I can change the code accordingly.

```
$new = array();

foreach ( $old as $occ => $val ) {

    // move over the first 14 from first row
    if ( $occ == 0 ) {
       for( $i=0; $i<14; $i++ ) {
            $new[] = $old[$occ][$i];
        }
        // setup the new measure array
        $new['measure'] = array();
    }

    $t = array();
    for ( $i=14; $i < 16; $i++ ) {
        $t[] = $old[$occ][$i];
    }
    $new['measure'][] = $t;

    $t = array();
    for ( $i=16; $i < count($old[$occ]); $i++ ) {
        $t[] = $old[$occ][$i];
    }
    $new['measure'][$occ]['comments'] = $t;
}
print_r($new);
```

And the result is :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Lot
    [2] => Lot Submission
    [3] => Lot Submission
    [4] => Lot Submission
    [5] => LNW North
    [6] => C Spencer Ltd
    [7] => Panel
    [8] => 1
    [9] => Buildings
    [10] => 2015/2016
    [11] => 2
    [12] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    [13] => Testing notes
    [measure] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => KPI1 - Behavioural Safety
                    [1] => PER1 - Health, Safety, and Wellbeing strategy
                    [comments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Testing Comment 1
                            [1] => Expected
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => KPI1 - Behavioural Safety
                    [1] => PMTEST - Test
                    [comments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Testing 2
                            [1] => Stretch
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => KPI1 - Behavioural Safety
                    [1] => JP001 - Jamie
                    [comments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Testing 3
                            [1] => Excellence
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Was this any use to you?

Comment: Just managed to get back to my computer. No this doesn't working unfortunately. However this is very close. I will have a play around and update this question

Comment: In what way does it not work? It produces the output you wanted, except for the fact that the indexes in `measure` and `comment` start at `0`. If you actually want them to use the same indexes as in your question, thats easily done. Let me know!

Comment: Since then I have had to update my code, i will update my question

Comment: No it works fine, but my structure has changed. See my updated question

Comment: Its not the done think to change a question once it has been asked and answered. You should really finish this one and ask another question

Comment: I have created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365414/php-group-together-different-parts-of-array-from-csv